# how do I use one script for multiple buttons/links?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hyperlink

this is gonna be probably a basic thing to answer too as I'm learning to code html/css/js and to do so I'm building a random website for a company that doesn't even know I exist.

So I have built a side nav menu with LINKS ()that show modal windows on-click so that the website remains a one-page website and one of those is a "ask an estimate" form that so far send info to nowhere (I will learn that later on).
Now, on the main page, I have made a series of hero banners to display their products and on each one of them I want to add a "ask an estimate" BUTTON () that show the same modal window as the link in the side nav. (probably will do the same with the contact link on one of those banners)

Now this is the code I'm using (most of it from w3):

Javascript file:

```
var modalPreventivo = document.getElementById("modalPreventivo");

var btnPreventivo = document.getElementById("btnPreventivo");

var spanPreventivo = document.getElementsByClassName("closePreventivo")[0];

btnPreventivo.onclick=function() {
    modalPreventivo.style.display= "block";
    
}

spanPreventivo.onclick = function() {
    modalPreventivo.style.display = "none";
}

windowPreventivo.onclick = function(eventPreventivo) {
    if (eventPreventivo.target == modalPreventivo) {
        modalPreventivo.style.display = "none";
   
    }
}
```

HTML on the link (works good Preventivo=Estimate)

```
<li><a href="#preventivo" id="btnPreventivo">Preventivo</a></li>
        <div id="modalPreventivo" class="modalPreventivo">
            <div class="modal-contentPreventivo">
                <div class="container">
                    <span class="closePreventivo">&times;</span>
                    <h1>Chiedi ora il tuo preventivo gratuitamente e senza impegno!</h1><br>
                    <form action="/action_page.php">
                      <label for="fname">Nome</label><br>
                      <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Il tuo nome">
                      <br>
                      <label for="lname">Cognome</label><br>
                      <input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Il tuo cognome">
                      <br>
                      <label for="country">E-mail (solo per ricontattarvi no spam)</label><br>
                      <input type="text" id="Email" name="email" placeholder="Il tuo indirizzo di posta elettronica">
                      <br>
                      <label for="subject">Come possiamo aiutarvi?</label><br>
                      <textarea id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Scrivici i dettagli della tua richiesta!" style="height:200px"></textarea>
                      <br>
                      <input type="submit" value="Richiedi ora!">
                    </form>
                 </div>
                
                
            </div>

        </div> 
            <script src="/Odorici/Javascript/preventivo.js"></script>
```

HTML button on hero banner (doesn't work at all)

```
        <div class="hero-image" style="background-image: url(/Odorici/img/sliding\ gate.jpg);">
                <div class="hero-text">
                  <h1>Cancelli Carrai</h1>
                  <p>Produciamo: 
                    <ul> 
                      <li>Cancelli carrai scorrevoli ciechi</li>
                      <li>Cancelli carrai scorrevoli normali</li> 
                      <li>Cancelli carrai ad anta ciechi</li>
                      <li>Cancelli carrai ad anta normali in ferro</li>
                    </ul>
                    Su misura e con la possibilità di verniciatura e zincatura a caldo.</p>
                  <button type="button" id="btnPreventivo" >Richiedi Preventivo</button>
                  
                </div>
              </div>
```

I forgot to put the CSS (thanks KEN!)

```
.modalPreventivo {
    display:none; /* Hidden by default */
    position:fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 50px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); /* Black w/ opacity */
    float: center;
    
    
  }
  
  /* Modal Content */
  .modal-contentPreventivo {
    display: block;
    background-color: wheat;
    color:goldenrod;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
  }
  
  /* The Close Button */
  .closePreventivo {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .closePreventivo:hover,
  .closePreventivo:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  input[type=text], select, textarea {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: 6px;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
    resize: vertical;
  }
  
  input[type=submit] {
    background-color: goldenrod;
    color: #7a1818;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #111;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: rgb(16, 172, 16);
    color: goldenrod;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

In the beginning, I thought that using the same ID would have work (also because while building the menu the "contacts" link has been showing the "estimate" form instead of its own "contact" modal window, but it won't work.

I tried to copy and paste the whole code from the "estimate" LINK with all the  boxes and the  and it won't work, I tried changing id, using href #preventivo, but I feel like nothing works cause I'm probably using the wrong functions or maybe I'm coding something wrong in the  ... I can't figure it out!

When I google this problem I read many articles that use Jquery (?) but I feel this should be much easier since when I didn't want this modal showing on the wrong link on the menu, it would have kept showing up (and it took me a while to fix that!) but now that I want it to show up on several links/buttons it won't...

Comment: Is "windowPreventivo" the same as "modalPreventivo"?

Comment: Your CSS code is missing, you should include all the code related to your issue.

Comment: Two things. Are the forms used at the same time on the page? Reason I'm asking is because you could only have one id at the time. Also is there a reason you choose to style the buttons via javascript instead of adding a css class to them?

Comment: Dejan.S yes the website is a one-page only, the form shows up in a modal window when I click the link in the menu on the sidenav and I'd like to have the same modal window to pop-up also when I press the buttons on the hero banners.

Ken, I'm not sure, I copied and paste straight from w3 and start working on it to learn as I'm new to this!